# Converting Month character to date for time series without "0" before Month

Tags: r

How do I convert this data set into a time series format in R? Lets call the data set Bob. This is what it looks like

1. 1/2013  25
2. 2/2013  865
3. 3/2013  26
4. 4/2013  33
5. 5/2013  74
6. 6/2013  24

Comment: month/year and what is the final column?

Comment: The final column is named height

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this....?

```
> dat <- read.table(text = "1/2013 25
  2/2013 865
  3/2013 26
  4/2013 33
  5/2013 74
  6/2013 24
 ", header=FALSE) # your data

> ts(dat$V2, start=c(2013, 1), frequency = 12) # time series object
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
2013  25 865  26  33  74  24
```

Comment: This works but how do I save the new ts output under a unique name? When I tired to save the new data set using "NewData<-ts(dat$V2, start=c(2013, 1), frequency = 12)", nothing worked.

Comment: I received all NAs for the date

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your starting point is the data frame `DF` defined reproducibly in the Note at the end this converts it to a zoo series `z` as well as a ts series `tt`.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(DF, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%m/%Y")
tt <- as.ts(z)

z
## Jan 2013 Feb 2013 Mar 2013 Apr 2013 May 2013 Jun 2013 
##       25      865       26       33       74       24 

tt
##      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
## 2013  25 865  26  33  74  24
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "1/2013 25
2/2013 865
3/2013 26
4/2013 33
5/2013 74
6/2013 24"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```